# detected any changes on the page with jQuery and function .live()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<span id="one"> one </span>
<span id="two"> two </span>


$("#one").mouseover(function(){
   $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
});

$("#two").click(function(){
   $(this).css('background-color', 'green');
});


    if (any changes on the site) {
        alert('changes detected');
    }
```

how can i detected any changes on the page?  is this possible? i would like use function **.live()**, but how?

**i dont want check separately each function on page.**

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/d4PMB/1/

Comment: Works fine in Google Chrome : http://jsfiddle.net/d4PMB/2/ or better http://jsfiddle.net/d4PMB/3/

Comment: i cant define any changes. in Firefox doesnt work

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/d4PMB/3/ works fine in Google Chrome 15, FF 7.0.1, IE 9 and Opera 11.52 and Safari 5.11!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to identify when the DOM has been changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744706/how-to-identify-when-the-dom-has-been-changed)

Comment: @ComFreek: this working only for first change

Comment: @PaulAttuck Then try this example: http://jsfiddle.net/d4PMB/6/

Comment: thanks, this working good :) please add answer for this question with this jsfiddle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use `window.setTimeout()`, capture the current HTML of the body (`document.body.innerHTML`) and compare it with the previous saved HTML:

```
var lastBodyHTML = "";
var changes = 0;

function test() {
    if (lastBodyHTML == "") {
        lastBodyHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
    }

    if (lastBodyHTML != document.body.innerHTML) {
        changes++;
        alert("CHANGE #" + changes);
        lastBodyHTML = document.body.innerHTML;
    }
    window.setTimeout(test, 1000);

};

test();
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/d4PMB/7/

Answer (score 3):

You can deal with `DOMAttrModified` too, it is more clean than setting a timeout on your page...

See this jsfiddle example : http://jsfiddle.net/d4PMB/9/

An alert message in displayed ONLY when the dom has changed, seems to be what you want, you can also full customize it, with event type.

Comment: Thanks, you can put this response as 'valid answer' for others ;)

Comment: There's no alert box in Google Chrome (16) when I modify or add an attribute or tag via Chrome Web Inspector.

Comment: @ComFreek, yes you're right : "WebKit doesn’t support DOMAttrModified consistently at the moment so Safari and Chrome currently have to use the slower setInterval mechanism." here is a good article about that : http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2011/Feb/22/A-jQuery-Plugin-to-monitor-Html-Element-CSS-Changes