# jQuery: How to listen for DOM changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

Is it possible and how can I listen for changes through the entire DOM tree with jQuery?

My specific issue: I have a 'tooltip' function that displays the contents of the `title` attribute in a stylish way when you do a `hover` on any html element. When you do a hover, however, by standard the browser renders the `title` in its own box. I would like to supress that. So what I've thought of is to move the contents of the `title` attribute to a custom (HTML5) `data-title` attribute the first time the page is loaded, and then my tooltip function will work with `data-title`.

The problem is that later on I might add / remove / change the HTML dynamically, so I need to 'rebind' those elements - change those title attrs again. It would be nice if there was an event listener that would listen for such changes for me and rebind the elements automatically.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to identify when the DOM has been changed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744706/how-to-identify-when-the-dom-has-been-changed)

Comment: seems like trying to listen to every change in DOM...and search for your elements each time would be really expensive.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a jQuery DOM change listener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

My best guess is that you want to listen to DOM mutation events.
You can do that by DOM mutation event as any normal javascript event such as a mouse click.

Refer to this : [W3 MutationEvent](http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-DOM-Level-2-Events-20001113/events.html#Events-MutationEvent)

Example:

```
$("element-root").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", "CustomHandler");
```

Comment: You do not need quotation marks on the handler, it's one way to get the function to be binded to the event.

Comment: this code may look short and sweet but the load it puts on browser is beyond inneficient for this use case when event delegation solutions below exist

Comment: My mistake .. I added quotations in a hurry

Comment: DOMSubtreeModified should be surrounded with quotes, however.

Comment: Mutation Events have been [deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationEvent).

Comment: Use Mutation Observer instead

Answer (score 2):

[edited in reply to research by member Tony]

So, without additional code, this is a bit of a blind shot, but it seems to me there are two things to think about here: 1. the default browser tooltip behaviour; 2. a potentially updated DOM and the ability for your custom tooltips to continue functioning.

Regarding #1: <del>when you bind your custom event to the element, you can use `event.preventDefault()` so that the tooltips don't appear.</del> This doesn't work properly. So, the workaround to keep using the "title" attribute is to grab the value, push it into the data object (the `$.data()` function), and then null the title with an empty string (removeAttr is inconsistent). Then on mouseleave, you grab the value out of the data object and push it back into the title. This idea comes from here: [How to disable tooltip in the browser with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1027762/how-to-disable-tooltip-in-the-browser-with-jquery)

Regarding #2: instead of re-binding on DOM change, you just need to bind once to a listener element that is never expected to be destroyed. Usually this is a container element of some sort, but it can even be `document` (approximating `.live()` which is now deprecated) if you really need an all-encompassing container. Here's a sample that uses some fake markup of my own devising:

```
var container = $('.section');

container.on('mouseenter', 'a', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var theTitle = $this.attr('title');
    $this.attr('title', '');
    $('#notatooltip').html(theTitle);   
    $.data(this, 'title', theTitle);
});

container.on('mouseleave', 'a', function() {
    $('#notatooltip').html('');
    var $this = $(this);
    var storedTitle = $.data(this, 'title');
    $this.attr('title', storedTitle);
});
```

My unrealistic markup (just for this example) is here:

```
<div class="section">
  <a href="#" title="foo">Hover this foo!</a>
  <div id="notatooltip"></div>
</div>
```

And a fiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/GVDqn/
Or with some sanity checks: http://jsfiddle.net/GVDqn/1/

There's probably a more optimal way to do this (I honestly didn't research if you could bind two separate functions for two separate events with one selector) but it'll do the trick.

You shouldn't need to re-bind based on DOM change, the delegated listener will automatically handle it. And you should be able to prevent default tooltip functionality just by preventing it.

Comment: most sensible approach here!....  then within the mouseenter can test if title has been moved to $(this).data('title') or not

Comment: would have been the most elegant solution, but it seems that `preventDefault` DOES NOT prevent showing titles on `mouseover` (at least in Chrome) - http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42549

Comment: @Tony Good find; I think it failed in Fx, too. I've updated with new code.

Comment: @charlietfl I didn't catch your meaning at first but now I'm with you!

Comment: @Greg still needs a minor tweak , if title has already been removed will end up with empty string stored in data

Comment: @charlietfl Code can always be optimized. ;-) No point doing someone else's work for them from end-to-end; this is just a pointer in the right direction. For production, I'd audit and test the functionality a bit more carefully.

Comment: understood...   my note may just help someone later on.... listening to the DOM changes just makes no sense as best solution

Comment: Couldn't help myself, Charlie... how's this? I feel dirty using truthiness and falsiness but it seems to work. http://jsfiddle.net/GVDqn/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to look at this here: http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents

Answer (score 0):

As noted by Greg Pettit, you should be using the on() function on the element.

What this does is allows you to bind a selector to an event, then jQuery will add this event handler when the objects returned by the selector are available.

If you wanted a function to fire on a mouse over event and you wanted it to fire on all elements with the class of ***field_title*** you would do this:

```
$('.field_title').bind('mouseenter', function() { doSomething(); });
```

This will trigger on the over mouse over event on any objects that have the class of ***field_title*** and execute the function ***doSomething()***.

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: You have a typo, should be `.bind('mouseenter')` not `.('mouseenter')`.