# Accessing element immediately after creation (without setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

*I have tried to search for an answer to this, but my wording is too similar to the questions that are looking for event delegation using the jQuery `on()` method. Consequently, please do not get confused by the wording of my question.*

I feel ashamed that I am actually asking this question given my experience with writing jQuery applications, but I must confess that I do not actually know the answer to this :-(

Consider this:

```
// Create the div
$('#wrapper').prepend('<div id="test"></div>');

// Add content to the div, and attach events
// Only execute it once the div has been created though, so wait 20 milliseconds
setTimeout(function(){

    // Add some button
    $('#test').html('<button></button>');

    // Add an event to the button
    // ... after 20 milliseconds
    setTimeout(function(){

        // Attach the click event
        $('#test button').click('dosomething');
    });
},20);
```

In the above code, I have had to use `setTimeout` to ensure that the element has been created before selecting it and adding content, events etc...

My question, quite simply, is there a better way to do this? Without timeouts?

**Please note I do not mean, *is there a better way to write the exact code above?* I simply want to know if there is a way to avoid using timeouts for the reason specified.**

Comment: *"I have had to use `setTimeout` to ensure that the element has been created before selecting it and adding content, events etc..."* No you don't. http://jsfiddle.net/LVH7w/

Comment: Perhaps I don't get what is the need of the inmediately created, why can't you use on?

Comment: @thesystem Funnily enough that is how I originally wrote my code, but it didnt work! It only worked once I inserted the timeouts. That is why I am so confused!!! :-(

Comment: Appending new children or HTML is synchronous operation, so you don't need any timeout.

Comment: @dfsq I know, that is why I am so confused. I only added the timeouts because it didnt work without them

Comment: @thesystem Okay, will do my best. My application is very large, this is just a small snippet. Might take me some time to create a working jsFiddle. Thanks for your help so far. I am glad that you agree the timeouts are not necessary...

Comment: @thesystem I am struggling to recreate the issue now. Not helped by the fact that I wrote this code a few months ago. I saw it today and noticed these nested timeouts. I then remembered why I put them there, and resultantly wanted to see if it was normal. I can't understand why it wasn't working before, and now it is. Sod's bloody law eh! I will post something here if I am able to recreate this. I am sure I will be, as this is not the first time I have encountered this issue... Thanks anyway, and sorry to waste your time

Comment: @BenCarey: No problem. Let me know if you figure it out. I know sometimes people use timeouts if it takes a long time for the browser to redraw the window, but that should usually only happen when you're appending a very large DOM.

Comment: @thesystem This is a very large DOM. Are you saying that timeouts might be necessary on a very large page, especially if the clients computer is not very good? or is this irrelavent?

Comment: @BenCarey: When appending a lot of new elements at the same time, it can freeze the browser a bit. Some people might break up the append using  `setTimeout`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could help.

```
 var _b = $('<button></button>');
    $('#wrapper').prepend(_b);
    _b.click(function(){
     ///do something
    });
```

Comment: no need for the `</button>`, jQuery will create the element for you with just `$('<button>')`

Comment: Thanks for you help, I will come back when I am able to recreate the exact issue in a jsFiddle. It now seems to be working, cannot understand why as it definitely wasnt before...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the wrapper exists on the DOM when you are adding the code try:

```
$('#wrapper').on('click', '#test button', doSomething)
```

Comment: Please read the question, I am not looking for event delegation. I am well aware of how to achieve this!

Comment: So if you don't need event delegation what do you need? To listen to the change in the DOM? What are you thoughs about this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488653/jquery-how-to-listen-for-dom-changes

Answer (score 0):

This works for me [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TxNzw/)

```
var $test = $('<div id="test"></div>');
  , $button = $('<button></button>')
$test.append($button);

$button.click(function() {
  console.log('here');
});

$('#wrapper').prepend($test);
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, I will come back when I am able to recreate the exact issue in a jsFiddle. It now seems to be working, cannot understand why as it definitely wasnt before...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I will do it in one line: http://fiddle.jshell.net/4rT6s/1/

```
$(function(){
    $('<button type="button">Click!</button>').click(function(){alert('click');}).appendTo($('<div id="test" />').appendTo('#wrapper'));
});
```

Comment: Thanks for you help, I will come back when I am able to recreate the exact issue in a jsFiddle. It now seems to be working, cannot understand why as it definitely wasnt before...

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can chain the methods with a little hack to get the children just created:

```
$('#wrapper').prepend('<div id="test"></div>').children('#test').html('<button></button>').children('button').click('dosomething');
```

it's ugly but it seems to work, i'm not sure if it's scalable to your needs

Comment: Thanks for you help, I will come back when I am able to recreate the exact issue in a jsFiddle. It now seems to be working, cannot understand why as it definitely wasnt before...