# Observe html body with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to **observe my html body**?

I have a css class: **.abdala** and this script:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".abdala").each(function (e) {
            alert("Abdala css class found");
        });
    });
</script>
```

I need observe the html body changes.

If i do that:

```
$(document.body).append("<div class=\"abdala\">another abadala element</div>");
```

After append i need do something. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: There's a hardly usable API called `MutationObserver` in case you're interested: http://addyosmani.com/blog/mutation-observers/ - cannot recommend to use that in production though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the class/id of the element AND have control when it changes, you could simple subscribe to the "change" event after the update.

**HTML**

```
<span class="abcd"> something</span>
<div id="log"></div>
<button id="change">change</button>
```

**JavaScript**

```
(function () {
    // basic helper to log when changes happen
    var log = function (message) {
        $("#log").append(message);
    };

    // the event that triggers the change
    $('#change').on('click', function (e) {
        $('.abcd').append('...more').trigger('change');
    });

    // the event that riggers the change
    $('.abcd').on('change', function (e) {
        log(new Date().toJSON() + ": this has changed</br>");
    });

})();
```

**JsFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/anAgent/xyzDL/1/

Comment: Buyer beware: `The change event is fired for <input>, <select>, and <textarea> elements when a change to the element's value is committed by the user. Unlike the input event, the change event is not necessarily fired for each change to an element's value.

` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change - This will only fire on form elements!

Answer (score 1):

This was answered in another question

[How to detect new element creation in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3384398/how-to-detect-new-element-creation-in-jquery)

It looks like there is a plugin for it, but it seems pretty bad since its not native to jQuery. It could really effect performance because the browser has to use more resources to keep checking for an element change.

AngularJS is perfect for that kind of operation, but jQuery isn't.

Comment: Thanks for referer link!

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a listener to do this, but you can create a `setInterval` and check regularly:

```
var oldBody = $('body').html();
function check() {
    if (oldBody != $('body').html()) {
        alert('Body html changed');
        oldBody = $('body').html();
    }
}

setInterval(check, 10); // checks every 10 milliseconds
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488653/jquery-how-to-listen-for-dom-changes) is what you are looking for.

However, I don't recommend it.

If you have something else that needs to be done after appending then just do it.

```
$(document.body).append("<div class=\"abdala\">another abadala element</div>");

callNextFunctionHere();
```

Why go to more trouble than this ?