# How to re-run JavaScript when DOM mutates?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I'm using Template.rendered to setup a dropdown replacement like so:

```
Template.productEdit.rendered = function() {
    if( ! this.rendered) {
        $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();
        this.rendered = true;
    }
};
```

But how do I re-run this when the DOM mutates? Helpers return new values for the select options, but I don't know where to re-execute my .dropdown()

Comment: Which dropdown plugin is this? I'm guessing it emits some kind of event which you can attach functions to

Comment: in which case this is more of a general javascript/jquery question than a meteor question

Comment: Nope, it's definitely a Meteor question. Meteor changes the DOM, so I need to trigger the dropdown to reset immediately after the DOM changes. I need a callback from Meteor to in which to trigger the dropdown plugin to be reset.

Answer (score 2):

I think you don't want this to run before the whole DOM has rendered, or else the event handler will run on EVERY element being inserted:

```
var rendered = false;
Template.productEdit.rendered = function() {rendered: true};
```

To avoid rerunning this on elements which are already dropdowns, you could give new ones a class which you remove when you make them into dropdowns

```
<div class="ui dropdown not-dropdownified"></div>
```

You could add an event listener for DOMSubtreeModified, which will do something only after the page has rendered:

```
Template.productEdit.events({
    "DOMSubtreeModified": function() {
        if (rendered) {
            var newDropdowns = $('.ui.dropdown.not-dropdownified');
            newDropdowns.removeClass("not-dropdownified");
            newDropdowns.dropdown();
        }
    }
});
```

This should reduce the number of operations done when the event is triggered, and could stop the callstack from being exhausted

Comment: Thanks, although for me this crashed the browser. 'Maximum Call Stack Exceeded'. I did read that observing MutationEvent can be dangerous, I'm going to have to figure out a workaround.

Comment: See the edit about a possible way to get around this

Comment: Also, could you add the javascript tag to this question? I think that might make the syntax highlighting of code work

Comment: I'm trying the newer Mutation method described here, because apparently DOMSubtreeModified is deprecated: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener/11546242#11546242

Answer (score 1):

Here's my tentative answer, it works but I'm still hoping Meteor has some sort of template mutation callback instead of this more cumbersome approach:

```
Template.productEdit.rendered = function() {
    if( ! this.rendered) {
        $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown();

        var mutationOptions = {
            childList: true,
            subtree: true
        }

        var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer){
            observer.disconnect(); // otherwise subsequent DOM changes will recursively trigger this callback

            var selectChanged = false;

            mutations.map(function(mu) {
                var mutationTargetName = Object.prototype.toString.call(mu.target).match(/^\[object\s(.*)\]$/)[1];
                if(mutationTargetName === 'HTMLSelectElement') {
                    console.log('Select Changed');
                    selectChanged = true;
                }
            });

            if(selectChanged) {
                console.log('Re-init Select');
                $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('restore defaults');
                $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('refresh');
                $('.ui.dropdown').dropdown('setup select');
            }

            mutationObserver.observe(document, mutationOptions); // Start observing again
        });

        mutationObserver.observe(document, mutationOptions);

        this.rendered = true;
    }
};
```

This approach uses [MutationObserver](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#mutationobserver) with some syntax help I found [here](https://dev.opera.com/articles/mutation-observers-tutorial/)

Answer (score -1):

Taking ad educated guess, and assuming you are using the [Semantic UI Dropdown](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/) plugin, there are four callbacks you can define:

**onChange(value, text, $choice)**: Is called after a dropdown item is selected. receives the name and value of selection and the active menu element

**onNoResults(searchValue)**: Is called after a dropdown is searched with no matching values

**onShow**: Is called after a dropdown is shown.

**onHide**: Is called after a dropdown is hidden.

To use them, give the dropdown() function a parameter:

```
$(".ui.dropdown").dropdown({
    onChange: function(value, text, $choice) {alert("You chose " + text + " with the value " + value);},
    onNoResults: function(searchValue) {alert("Your search for " + searchValue + " returned no results");}
    onShow: function() {alert("Dropdown shown");},
    onHide: function() {alert("Dropdown hidden");}
});
```

I suggest you read the [documentation](http://semantic-ui.com/modules/dropdown.html#/usage) of all plugins you use.

Comment: Sorry, but it's not a general JS question. It's about Meteor DOM changes and triggering subsequent code, in this case a dropdown plugin.

The above plugin API methods don't suffice. The onChange() for example is for when a user selects a new value, but I need to reset the plugin based on the underlying DOM change due to Meteor reactivity.

Comment: I still find it to be a general jQuery/javascript question, and a possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9488653/jquery-how-to-listen-for-dom-changes
At least I got it to run a function every time the DOM changed using answers from there.
You could possibly stuff it into a Meteor event handler

Comment: I'm still looking for a proper Meteor callback after it has modified a template but there doesn't seem to be one?

I'll look at MutationEvent as suggested, it looks like a pretty good solution thank you for the suggestion.