# When adding an element to a list what is the best way to trigger this event

Tags: javascript, events, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to identify when the DOM has been changed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3744706/how-to-identify-when-the-dom-has-been-changed)

Let's suppose I have access to the `<ul>` element `$(ul#mylist)`.
How can I trigger the event when some item is added to the list.

I tried the following but actually it does not work.

```
$('ul#mylist').change(function () {
    console.log('added an element');
});
```

Comment: What is adding the item to the list?

Comment: If you're the one adding it to the list, you should run the code manually at that time. I wouldn't rely on DOM Mutation methods for this.

Answer (score 6):

You can try listening to `DOMNodeInserted`  event

```
$('ul#mylist').on('DOMNodeInserted' ,function () {
    console.log('added an element');
});
```

If you are adding a li to ul and want to Listen to the event..

[Check DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/PgAJT/9/)

Comment: +1 Very good!, didn't know about that event, I've extended your demo to also show how to use it to listen to any element added on the page and figure out the element type or attributes based on event.target parameter. Here --> http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/9DPUY/

Comment: Wow, I didn't know that existed either!

Comment: Note that DOM mutation events (e.g. DOMNodeInserted) are deprecated because the design is flawed. See [MDN reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/DOM_event_reference). It recommends to use [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FDOM_Mutation_Observers) instead.